# Does returning a pre-created table create a new one?

Tags: lua

If I run this piece of code

```lua
MyTable = {}
function SomeFunction()
 return MyTable
end
SomeFunction()
```

Does it create a new table or return a pre-created table?

So far, I don't know exactly how I can check that with current methods. I know

Comment: I think you should be feeding your function with the table this way: `function SomeFunction(MyTable)` in order to expect it to be returned and, as fas as I know, it would return the table itself, not a new one. Regarding how to know if the table is the same, normally I use `print(tostring(MyTable))` so I can see if they have the same identifier, but it's not something I have to do a lot, so it may be better ways... Well, hope it helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's walk through the execution of the code:

1. A new table is created: `{}`
2. The new table (or rather, *the* reference to it) is assigned to the global variable `MyTable`
3. A function is defined.
4. The function is assigned to the global variable `SomeFunction`
5. The global variable `SomeFunction` is accessed
6. The result of the access is called
7. We enter the execution of `SomeFunction`:

   1. The global variable `MyTable` is accessed
   2. The result of the access is returned - this will be the table (or rather, *the* reference to it) initially created

So no, `SomeFunction` will not copy `MyTable` - it will return the reference to the already existing table. For the creation of a table inside `SomeFunction`, you would need a table constructor inside `SomeFunction`: `function SomeFunction() return {} end` would create a new table each time it is called.

As Ramon has pointed out, you can use `print(MyTable)` to print the reference to a table (e.g. to verify that it doesn't change).

You might want to localize `MyTable` to make it an "upvalue" rather than a "global variable".